# VHDL Moving average: simulation & synthesis result differ (Vivado)

Tags: vhdl, simulation, moving-average, synthesis

For my project I need to reduce a noise of an ADC output and implemented a simple moving average filter in VHDL.

Although it works in simulation (see the picture): 
[image: simulation of moving average]
 it has some strange behavior if I display it on the chipscope when the system is running in FPGA (see the picture):
[image]

The VHDL code I use for the moving average is as follows:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.math_real.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity moving_avg is
    generic(
         SAMPLES_COUNT      : integer := 32
    );
    port (
         clk_i              : in   std_logic;
         rst_n_i            : in   std_logic;
         sample_i           : in   std_logic_vector(11 downto 0);
         avg_o              : out  std_logic_vector(11 downto 0)
    );
end;

architecture rtl of moving_avg is

    type     sample_buff_t    is array (1 to SAMPLES_COUNT) of std_logic_vector(11 downto 0);
    signal   sample_buffer  : sample_buff_t;
    signal   sum            : std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
    constant wid_shift      : integer := integer(ceil(log2(real(SAMPLES_COUNT))));
    signal   avg_interm_s   : std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);

begin

    process (clk_i, rst_n_i) begin
        if rst_n_i='1' then
            sample_buffer <= (others => sample_i);
            sum <= std_logic_vector(unsigned(resize(unsigned(sample_i), sum'length))  sll wid_shift) ;
        elsif rising_edge(clk_i) then
            sample_buffer <= sample_i & sample_buffer(1 to SAMPLES_COUNT-1);
            sum <= std_logic_vector(unsigned(sum) + unsigned(sample_i) - unsigned(sample_buffer(SAMPLES_COUNT)));
        end if;
    end process;

    avg_interm_s <= std_logic_vector((unsigned(sum) srl wid_shift));
    avg_o <= avg_interm_s(11 downto 0);

end;
```

I use Xilinx Vivado tool 2015.2 running on Ubuntu 14.04 x64.

Could you please help me to identify the problem, such 
that results in simulation correspond to results after synthesis?

Comment: If you are using Xilinx ISIM, make sure you have turned the runtime checks on. Otherwise it will hide arithmetic problems like over-and under-flow. What you're seeing looks like a combination of an unexpected DC shift or constant offset (why aren't you clearing SUM in the reset clause?) and an overflow/wrapround somewhere.

Comment: It looks to me like the chipscope display is treating the moving average as unsigned. I've not used it that much, can you try changing the radix of the display?